# apt-get update fails on chroot ubuntu 16.04 on android

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, apt

I installed xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) in a chroot on my Android device (using armhf architecture). Everything works just fine. All the local commands and wget and curl work fine. However, apt-get fails. Here is the issue:

1) "sudo apt-get update" gives me an error: Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com' (other programs such as wget and curl can access dns names successfully)

I pinged the servers and obtained the IP so I edit the /etc/apt/sources.list to reflect this

2) "sudo apt-get update" gives me another error: Could not create a socket for 91.189.88.150 (f=2 t=1 p=6) - socket (13: Permission denied)

3) Alright, so then I suid all the apt-* programs: sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/apt-*

To remove any questions about the specific apt-get version
I have removed apt via apt-get itself and installed the *apt*.deb via dpkg successfully, however, the problem persists.

It's very surprising that this basic feature on Ubuntu seems to be broken, it could be specific to armhf packages. I can't seem to find the same problem reported on SO. However, I did find another user reporting something similar on reddit's /r/debian but it was not concluded.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

PS: I don't have a reason to claim this is specific to Android system and I think this could be a general problem to chroot using armhf binaries. But I have just tested this on my setup with Android (the only arm device I can test with).

Comment: may belong to https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5):

According my experience, there are two possible reasons could result apt* failed to work under andoid enviroment.
1 empty DNS. You have to set DNS once you chroot into ubuntu, the simplest way is 'echo 'your_number_dns' >/etc/resolv.conf'
2 change the group of apt to 3003.  vi /etc/passwd    change the group of _apt from 65534 to 3003 . the result looks like '_apt:x:105:3003::/nonexistent:/bin/false'. The apt-get will change its from current user to the one assigned in the file passwd. but under android, user who is the member of inet can access socket normally, please refer 'system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h' for detail information. so change the group of apt to inet(3003 here) can resolve this problem.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Comment: Toby, can you help by pointing out what is not on topic here? The question is very specific about aptitude failing to update on Ubuntu running in a sandboxed environment on an Android device. The question has sufficient details to reproduce on a given setup and doesn't really seem restricted to Ubuntu-only or Android-only forums.
Assuming your concern is genuine I'd like to improve the questions. Can you point out?

Comment: Changing group worked!

Answer (score 1):

[what can cause a socket() "Permission denied" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451444/what-can-cause-a-socket-permission-denied-error)

and

echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf

worked for me.
Basically, this turned out to be a problem with root not being added to the right groups.